# WIFI AX200 suddenly stopped working on 22.04 after reboot

Tags: wireless, 22.04, iwlwifi

Running 22.04 on a Lenovo ideapad 5-15ARE05 (4800u) my Wifi suddenly stopped working yesterday after an update and reboot.

The Intel card is still recognized.

```
sudo lshw -C network
  *-network                 
       description: Network controller
       product: Wi-Fi 6 AX200
```

But it doesn't run.

```
syslog
 [   12.450481] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Transport status: 0x00000042, valid: 7
 [   12.450485] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x20100240 | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT
 [   12.450489] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | umac branchlink1
 [   12.450492] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x80455E3C | umac branchlink2
 [   12.450495] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x8046E886 | umac interruptlink1
 [   12.450498] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | umac interruptlink2
 [   12.450501] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0xDEADBEEF | umac data1
 [   12.450504] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0xDEADBEEF | umac data2
 [   12.450506] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0xDEADBEEF | umac data3
 [   12.450509] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000048 | umac major
 [   12.450512] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0xDAA05125 | umac minor
 [   12.450515] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00021493 | frame pointer
 [   12.450518] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0xC0886AE4 | stack pointer
 [   12.450521] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | last host cmd
 [   12.450524] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr status reg
 [   12.450815] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: IML/ROM dump:
 [   12.450818] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000003 | IML/ROM error/state
 [   12.450925] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00006201 | IML/ROM data1
 [   12.451037] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000080 | IML/ROM WFPM_AUTH_KEY_0
 [   12.451146] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Fseq Registers:
 [   12.451200] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x20000000 | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE
 [   12.451253] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x80290021 | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION
 [   12.451305] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00050008 | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
 [   12.451360] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x0000A503 | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION
 [   12.451414] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x80000003 | FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION
 [   12.451467] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x4552414E | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN
 [   12.451522] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00100530 | FSEQ_CNVI_ID
 [   12.451575] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000532 | FSEQ_CNVR_ID
 [   12.451629] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00100530 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP
 [   12.451686] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000532 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP
 [   12.451741] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x05B0905B | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM
 [   12.451797] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x0000025B | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR
 [   12.451849] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Failed to start RT ucode: -110
 [   12.451854] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: WRT: Collecting data: ini trigger 13 fired (delay=0ms).
```

When I boot an Ubuntu Live USB 20.04, the Wifi card is working, so it seems to be a regression from a recent update.

It's a Linux only laptop.

Booting an older kernel (5.15) on 22.04 doesn't help.

**UPDATE**
I also noted this line in dmesg

`Driver unable to support your firmware API. Driver supports v72, firmware is v73.`

**UPDATE 2**
This was not caused by an update. I upgraded my SSD and reinstalled Ubuntu 22.04, with all updates Wifi is still working.
Something else must have been broken in my old configuration.

Comment: Can you try kernel boot option `irqpoll` please ?

Comment: thx, irqpoll doesn't work: hangs during booting